# If m postive integers such $\rm{lcm}[a_{i},a_{j}]\le 400,\forall i,j\in \{1,2,\cdots,m\}$,prove $m\le 40$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Let $a_{i}$ be postive integers,and such $1\le a_{1}\le a_{2}\le\cdots\le a_{m}\le 400$, and $$\operatorname{lcm}[a_{i},a_{j}]\le 400,\forall i,j\in \{1,2,\cdots,m\}$$

show that $m\le 40$

if we note
$$\operatorname{lcm}[a_{i},a_{j}]=\dfrac{a_{i}\cdot a_{j}}{\operatorname{gcd}(a_{i},a_{j})}\le 400$$

$$\sum_{1\le i<j\le m}a_{i}a_{j}\le 400\sum_{1\le i<j\le m}\operatorname(a_{i},a_{j})$$Well and now I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed,this is Mathematics Olympic book excise problem

Comment: Are the numbers distinct? Because otherwise you can set all of them to 400.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:
Let $S$ be the set of numbers not divisible by 23. I claim that $|S| \leq 22$; indeed in each residue class mod 23, there can be at most one number in $S$, else we have:$lcm(23a+r,23b+r) \geq 529ab/gcd(b-a) \geq 529$.

The number of numbers which are divisible by 23 and at most 400 is at most 18.

Thus the total number is at most 40.